# cannot use 'precompiled-header' output with multiple -arch options

Tags: xcode4.5

I have an existing project and I tried to compile it with last Xcode version 4.5.2.
When I run it on simulator it works fine, but when I try to run it on iPhone or iPad I got the following error :

> clang: error: cannot use 'precompiled-header' output with multiple -arch options
>   Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Does anyone know what is the problem ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335752/clang-cannot-use-precompiled-header-output-with-multiple-arch-options