# clang: cannot use 'precompiled-header' output with multiple -arch options

Tags: c, xcode, gcc, clang

When compiling on of my projects, I suddenly got this error message when switching from Xcode 4.5 to Xcode 5.

```
clang: cannot use 'precompiled-header' output with multiple -arch options
```

My GNU `Makefile` contains the following fragment:

```
define build
CC-$(platform)-$(2)?=$(CC-$(platform))

$(bindir)/$(platformdir)-$(2)$($(3)-dirsuffix)/$(1)_%: $(srcdir)/$(1)/%.c $(common)
  mkdir -p $$(@D)
  $$(CC-$(platform)-$(2)) $(cflags) $($(3)-cflags) $(CFLAGS) -o $$@ $$^ $($(3)-ldflags) $(LDFLAGS)
endef

$(foreach library,$(libraries),$(foreach arch,$(archs),$(foreach configuration,$(configurations),$(eval $(call build,$(library),$(arch),$(configuration))))))
```

And `$(CC)` evaluates to `cc` which is symlinked to clang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [solution](http://pempek.net/articles/2013/10/12/clang-cannot-use-precompiled-header/) is to filter out header files from the list of files being
compiled by using GNU `Make`'s **`$(filter-out pattern...,text)`** function to filter out everything that matches `%.h`:

```
define build
CC-$(platform)-$(2)?=$(CC-$(platform))

$(bindir)/$(platformdir)-$(2)$($(3)-dirsuffix)/$(1)_%: $(srcdir)/$(1)/%.c $(common)
  mkdir -p $$(@D)
  $$(CC-$(platform)-$(2)) $(cflags) $($(3)-cflags) $(CFLAGS) -o $$@ $$(filter-out %.h,$$^) $($(3)-ldflags) $(LDFLAGS)
endef
```

And then `clang` isn't confused anymore.

Comment: that was obvious... *sigh*